# How to run SQL Update query in NiFi PUTSQL?

Tags: mysql, apache, sql-update, apache-nifi

I want to update a column `enum_value` of `tableB` with the values of another column `enum_value` in `tableA` using MySQL update query as follows:

```
UPDATE tableB t1 
INNER JOIN TableA t2 ON t1.sig_name = t2.sig_name
SET t1.enum_value = t2.enum_value
WHERE t1.dbc_Version = t2.dbc_version
```

The above SQL query runs fine in the MYSQL workbench, but I want to execute this query (perform this **Update** dynamically using **NiFi PUTSQL** (SQL Statement) property. When I write this in NiFi PutSQL, I get an error. I have attached the screenshots below:

[image: ConvertJsonTOSQL]

[image: PUTSQL SQLstatement]

[image: PUTSQL Error]

Is there I way I can achieve dynamic(on the fly update in the DB) using NiFi? If yes, Then how and what controller services needThanks in advance! to be set?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the query directly in PutSQL, what is the purpose of the ConvertJSONToSQL processor right before that? That processor generates attributes from the JSON data, which PutSQL looks for when trying to populate a prepared statement with parameters (which you don't have as you're using an explicit statement with no `?`s).

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734291/executesql-failing-after-putsql-processor/54774687#54774687) for more information, basically you should use UpdateAttribute to remove any attributes created by ConvertJSONToSQL.