# Issue with PutDatabaseRecord after JOLTTransformJSON when Inserting data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I am able to INSERT into Postgres DB from JOLTTransformJSON when using ConvertJSONToSQL (v1.13.2) and then PutSQL. But it fails when using PutDatabaseRecord after JOLTTransformJSON.

[image]
The error is:

`PutDatabaseRecord Failed to put Records to database java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Tue Oct 05 15:58:22 EDT 2021"`  and

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20201705101430"
```

[image: PutDatabaseRecord properties]

Schema for the RecordReader
[image]
I have detail_r table in DB where all columns have type character varying type. Some are of length 20 some 10 some are 8 as needed. I am assuming that jolt transform json fields should match with column names. Some columns are extra in table for which no field is available in json and vice-versa. Can this be an issue. I prefer using PutDatabaseRecord over PutSQL because after PutSQL there is ExecuteSQL which doesn't work well with PutSQL , so can this be done, or what is wrong in below approach.

Comment: What is your schema for the RecordReader?

Comment: @Sdairs I have UPDATED the question with Schema for RecordReader. It is default setting

Comment: @mattyb Can you suggest something. I want to use PutDatabaseRecord over PutSQL because of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734291/executesql-failing-after-putsql-processor and Delete Attributes Expression property to sql\.args\..* for UpdateAttribute doesn't work either